# How to run a function in a thread that takes a pointer argument and a reference in Win32 application?

Tags: c++, multithreading, win32gui

I am new to Win32 applications and threads. I have a application and two functions that are not member of any class and I would like to run them in separate threads. The function without arguments is fine but the one that takes 2 arguments one of which is a pointer I am getting a compile error.

The functions that I am trying to run in separate threads are `Func1()` and `Func2(ClassA* classA, ClassB& classB)`.

Here is the code:

```
// ThreadTestDesktop.cpp : Defines the entry point for the application.
//

#include "framework.h"
#include "ThreadTestDesktop.h"

#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

#include "ClassA.h"
#include "ClassB.h"

#define MAX_LOADSTRING 100

// Global Variables:
HINSTANCE hInst;                                // current instance
WCHAR szTitle[MAX_LOADSTRING];                  // The title bar text
WCHAR szWindowClass[MAX_LOADSTRING];            // the main window class name

// Forward declarations of functions included in this code module:
ATOM                MyRegisterClass(HINSTANCE hInstance);
BOOL                InitInstance(HINSTANCE, int);
LRESULT CALLBACK    WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);
INT_PTR CALLBACK    About(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);

ClassA classA;

void Func1();

int APIENTRY wWinMain(_In_ HINSTANCE hInstance,
                     _In_opt_ HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                     _In_ LPWSTR    lpCmdLine,
                     _In_ int       nCmdShow)
{
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(hPrevInstance);
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(lpCmdLine);

    // TODO: Place code here.

    // Initialize global strings
    LoadStringW(hInstance, IDS_APP_TITLE, szTitle, MAX_LOADSTRING);
    LoadStringW(hInstance, IDC_THREADTESTDESKTOP, szWindowClass, MAX_LOADSTRING);
    MyRegisterClass(hInstance);

    // Perform application initialization:
    if (!InitInstance (hInstance, nCmdShow))
    {
        return FALSE;
    }

    HACCEL hAccelTable = LoadAccelerators(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDC_THREADTESTDESKTOP));

    MSG msg;

    // Main message loop:
    while (GetMessage(&msg, nullptr, 0, 0))
    {
        if (!TranslateAccelerator(msg.hwnd, hAccelTable, &msg))
        {
            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessage(&msg);
        }
    }

    return (int) msg.wParam;
}



//
//  FUNCTION: MyRegisterClass()
//
//  PURPOSE: Registers the window class.
//
ATOM MyRegisterClass(HINSTANCE hInstance)
{
    WNDCLASSEXW wcex;

    wcex.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);

    wcex.style          = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wcex.lpfnWndProc    = WndProc;
    wcex.cbClsExtra     = 0;
    wcex.cbWndExtra     = 0;
    wcex.hInstance      = hInstance;
    wcex.hIcon          = LoadIcon(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_THREADTESTDESKTOP));
    wcex.hCursor        = LoadCursor(nullptr, IDC_ARROW);
    wcex.hbrBackground  = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW+1);
    wcex.lpszMenuName   = MAKEINTRESOURCEW(IDC_THREADTESTDESKTOP);
    wcex.lpszClassName  = szWindowClass;
    wcex.hIconSm        = LoadIcon(wcex.hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_SMALL));

    return RegisterClassExW(&wcex);
}

//
//   FUNCTION: InitInstance(HINSTANCE, int)
//
//   PURPOSE: Saves instance handle and creates main window
//
//   COMMENTS:
//
//        In this function, we save the instance handle in a global variable and
//        create and display the main program window.
//
BOOL InitInstance(HINSTANCE hInstance, int nCmdShow)
{
   hInst = hInstance; // Store instance handle in our global variable

   HWND hWnd = CreateWindowW(szWindowClass, szTitle, WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
      CW_USEDEFAULT, 0, CW_USEDEFAULT, 0, nullptr, nullptr, hInstance, nullptr);

   if (!hWnd)
   {
      return FALSE;
   }

   ShowWindow(hWnd, nCmdShow);
   UpdateWindow(hWnd);

   return TRUE;
}

//
//  FUNCTION: WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM)
//
//  PURPOSE: Processes messages for the main window.
//
//  WM_COMMAND  - process the application menu
//  WM_PAINT    - Paint the main window
//  WM_DESTROY  - post a quit message and return
//
//
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_COMMAND:
        {
            int wmId = LOWORD(wParam);
            // Parse the menu selections:
            switch (wmId)
            {
            case IDM_ABOUT:
                DialogBox(hInst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_ABOUTBOX), hWnd, About);
                break;
            case IDM_EXIT:
            {
                std::thread func1Thread(Func1);
                func1Thread.join();
            }
                DestroyWindow(hWnd);
                break;
            default:
                return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
            }
        }
        break;
    case WM_PAINT:
        {
            PAINTSTRUCT ps;
            HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);
            // TODO: Add any drawing code that uses hdc here...
            EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        }
        break;
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}

// Message handler for about box.
INT_PTR CALLBACK About(HWND hDlg, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(lParam);
    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_INITDIALOG:
        return (INT_PTR)TRUE;

    case WM_COMMAND:
        if (LOWORD(wParam) == IDOK || LOWORD(wParam) == IDCANCEL)
        {
            EndDialog(hDlg, LOWORD(wParam));
            return (INT_PTR)TRUE;
        }
        break;
    }
    return (INT_PTR)FALSE;
}

void Func2(ClassA* classA, ClassB& classB)
{
    std::cout << "Inside Func2 with param1 = " << &param1 << ", param2 = " << param2 << std::endl;
}

void Func1()
{
    ClassB classB;

    std::cout << "Inside Func1" << std::endl;

    std::thread func2Thread(Func2, &classA, classB);
    func2Thread.join();
}
```

The classes:

```
#pragma once
class ClassA
{
public:
    ClassA();
    ~ClassA();

};

#include "ClassA.h"
#include <iostream>

ClassA::ClassA()
{
    std::cout << "ClassA Constructor" << std::endl;
}

ClassA::~ClassA()
{
}

#pragma once
class ClassB
{
public:
    ClassB();
    ~ClassB();

};

#include "ClassB.h"
#include <iostream>

ClassB::ClassB()
{
    std::cout << "ClassB Constructor" << std::endl;
}

ClassB::~ClassB()
{
}
```

And this is the error I am getting:

```
Rebuild started...
1>------ Rebuild All started: Project: ThreadTestDesktop, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>ClassA.cpp
1>ClassB.cpp
1>ThreadTestDesktop.cpp
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29333\include\thread(43,14): error C2672: 'invoke': no matching overloaded function found
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29333\include\thread(49): message : see reference to function template instantiation 'unsigned int std::thread::_Invoke<_Tuple,0,1,2>(void *) noexcept' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Tuple=_Tuple
1>        ]
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29333\include\thread(55): message : see reference to function template instantiation 'unsigned int (__stdcall *std::thread::_Get_invoke<_Tuple,0,1,2>(std::integer_sequence<size_t,0,1,2>) noexcept)(void *)' being compiled
1>C:\Users\Lidiane\source\repos\ThreadTestDesktop\ThreadTestDesktop\ThreadTestDesktop.cpp(206): message : see reference to function template instantiation 'std::thread::thread<void(__cdecl &)(ClassA *,ClassB &),ClassA*,ClassB&,0>(_Fn,ClassA *&&,ClassB &)' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Fn=void (__cdecl &)(ClassA *,ClassB &)
1>        ]
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29333\include\thread(39,5): error C2893: Failed to specialize function template 'unknown-type std::invoke(_Callable &&,_Ty1 &&,_Types2 &&...) noexcept(<expr>)'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29333\include\type_traits(1588): message : see declaration of 'std::invoke'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29333\include\thread(39,5): message : With the following template arguments:
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29333\include\thread(39,5): message : '_Callable=void (__cdecl *)(ClassA *,ClassB &)'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29333\include\thread(39,5): message : '_Ty1=ClassA *'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29333\include\thread(39,5): message : '_Types2={ClassB}'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29333\include\thread(39,5): error C2780: 'unknown-type std::invoke(_Callable &&) noexcept(<expr>)': expects 1 arguments - 3 provided
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29333\include\type_traits(1582): message : see declaration of 'std::invoke'
1>Generating Code...
1>Done building project "ThreadTestDesktop.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
========== Rebuild All: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

What am I getting wrong and what is the best practice to pass arguments to threads when using them in Win32?

Comment: Try `std::thread func2Thread(Func2, &classA, std::ref (classB));`

Comment: @PaulSanders that works great. Thanks!

Comment: You do realize that `std::thread::join()` blocks the calling thread until the worker thread ends, don't you?  So `std::thread func1Thread(Func1); func1Thread.join();` is no better than simply calling `Func1();` as-is, and `std::thread func2Thread(Func2, &classA, classB); func2Thread.join();` is no better than simply calling `Func2(&classA, classB);` as-is.  You are not actually parallelizing your code.

Comment: @RemyLebeau That was the request in a task. Filling a shape from a picture with `Func2(ClassA* classA, ClassB& classB)`. I did try with `_beginthread` but did not work very well, that is very new for me. I got stucked when I had to pass the arguments for `Func2` so I went for the classic thread.

Comment: @s_diaconu You *should* be using `std::thread` instead of `_beginthread()`.  But you are not using threads *effectively*, or even *correctly*.  Neither thread you have shown makes sense in the contexts that you are using them. I think you have misunderstood the task you were given.

Comment: @RemyLebeau the task is saying to have `Func1` run  in a thread. In the real task `Func1` has a a for loop that calls `Func2` every iteration. The task is saying to have `Func2` to run using its own thread. All threads should run concurrently. That's all it says. On the mockup program the `std::thread func2Thread(Func2, &classA, std::ref (classB));' fixes the issues but not in the real one. The `Func2` in the real program updates a `BMP` image. not sure if it has something to do with that.

Comment: I am actually getting this error: `no instance of constructor "std::thread::thread" matches the argument list argument types are: (<unknown-type>, CDIB32 *, std::reference_wrapper<CPoint>)` and I looked evrywhere. I've seen that most of the cases are talking about functions that belong to some classes but that's not the case here. My functions are global.